# navigate by user type from Firebase on React-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-navigation

I have a type script that I manage all pages with navigation. I wrote a new 'class' on it and defined the stats. state also brings usertype from firebase and i want to write an if case according to this usertype in navigation. Isn't that possible? I keep a usertype in the Fire base and I will navigate the pages accordingly ???? But if you look at the code, I said to make a console debug before proceeding and I got an error. I share the screenshot of the error.

[image]

```
 class AppDatamiz  {


  state = {
    user: {}
  }
  unsubscribe = null ; 

  componentDidMount() {
    const user = this.props.uid || Fire.shared.uid

    this.unsubscribe = Fire.shared.firestore
        .collection("users")
        .doc(user)
        .onSnapshot(doc => {
            this.setState({ user: doc.data() });
        }); 
  }  

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe();
  }

  }    // CLASS IS OVER HERE

if({AppDatamiz.state.user.userType}=='Ogr')
{
  console.log('11111111111')
} 
const anaSayfaStack = createStackNavigator({              // ana sayfa stack
  anaSayfa: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: `Ana Sayfa`,

    }),
  },
}
  , {
    initialRouteName: 'anaSayfa',

  }
);


..

.
..
..                 //// ALLL OF STACKNAVİGATORSS AND BOTTOMTABNAVİGATORS
.   
..                  /// ALSO SWİTCH NAVS
...
.


export default createAppContainer(KesinSonSecimSwitch);
```

anyone can help???